# System runs out of space, space returns after restart

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, filesystem, storage

I have no many details except this -
After a while my system is using more than 80% of the file system but after the restart it returns to usage of 9%.
I have no idea why it happens and therefore I have no information on why and how.
If someone here is familiar with servers/Ubuntu I'd like to know how my system is running out of space during run-time but returns back to normal after a shutdown is conducted.
Thanks!

Comment: Use something like `Disk usage analyser` (GUI) or `ncdu` (CLI) to find what is taking the space. You should look particularly to `/tmp` (it is cleared on reboot)

Comment: All files in /tmp are being shown as 4.0KB in size using ls -lah

Comment: As @Salem said, `cd /` then `ncdu` and wait for it to finish. Then browse around and figure out what's taking up the space. You might have to install it with `sudo apt-get install ncdu`.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer, but some tips on how to identify the source of the problem.*

To find what is taking the space, you can do the following:

- First, get a listing of the occupied space of the root folders with `sudo du -h -d 1 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/run /`. This will give you some output like the following:

  ```
  309M    /opt
  3,8G    /var
  512K    /root
  (...)
  3,5M    /lib32
  ```

  Save this information somewhere and wait for the system to start filling again. Then, you execute the same command and compare the outputs. This should give you a hint on what is growing and taking your space.
- Then you can use `ncdu` to investigate further. Supposing that the folder that grow more was `/var`, you can use `sudo ncdu /var`. This is a curses application, so you can use the arrows and enter to navigate between the folders and get to the root of the problem.

But as I said in the comments, the fact that the space is reclaimed after yo restarted your system points to `/tmp`. This folder is used to store temporary files and is cleared whenever you restart by default. As you guess, as a server would be rarely rebooted the files there will start to pile up...